# How to find the $P_2$ when $T_1P_1=T_2P_2$

Tags: matrices, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

$T_1$ and $T_2$ are $3 \times 3$ homogenous transform matrices. $P_1$ is the $3 \times 1$ matrix with $x, y$ coordinates of point $P_1$.

What I am trying to do here is trying to get $x, y$ coordinate of point $P$ in coordinate system with transform $T_2$ when I know its $x, y$ in coordinate system with transform $T_1$.

Well in this relation it seems obvious that $P_2=T_2^{-1} \cdot T_1 \cdot P_1$. But this is giving wrong result in a code of mine. I am right now at my wit's end, so posted this question.

Are there any corner cases where this equation can fail? I know of one case when $\det(T_2)=0$.

Comment: What exactly are the $T_i$ and the $P_i$ that are giving you trouble? What results are you getting, and what results do you think you should see?

Comment: same question as above. Are the matrices represented in a symbolic way or numerical?

Comment: @J.M. For any values of $T_i$ and $P_i$ it gives me trouble. The value of $P_2$ I get is quite far off. I am not sure what's going on but I rechecked the program a number of times and the logic seems to be fine. From your response it seems there aren't any more corner cases. Then I guess I need to revisit my code again.

Comment: @newbie I really didn't get your question.

Comment: "any"? Something indeed is off. You keep saying "far off"but you didn't say exactly what you're seeing and what you think you should be seeing...

Comment: as you mentioned codes a several times, i think those matrices are given in a numerical way. if you could explain in more details about your program, it may help us to understand. what are the transform matrices' role: transform(from one point to the other), rotation, or reflection(flip)? How do you describe them, e.g. $\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} $?

Comment: @newbie It is like your example except that it has one more column and row. As shown at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations).

Comment: So, could you give it explicitly? Because if it is a rotation matrix, the determinant would never be 0. Or, I advice you to go through your codes carefully once more: pay extra attention to details, brackets, parenthesis, etc, and also if/while/for loops if applicable. If the matrixe setting is right, there must be somethings wrong in the code implementation.

Comment: Or, to simplify the problem, insteading transforming twice(one forward one backward), try to use ONE transform matrix: if $T_{1}$ is composed by angle $\alpha$ and $T_{2}$ by $\gamma$, then use $T$ composed by angle $\alpha - \gamma$. It allows you to avoid the computation of inverse matrix and matrix operation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take this answer as an answer. I'm writing here simply because it is easier to edit. Here we go.

Say $\tilde{x}$ is a vector lying in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space(your Euclidean space).

If you only have one transform variable, it only allows you to transfrom in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (sub)space. In order to transform in 3D, you need two angle variables.

Check [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotations_in_three_dimensions) for the details. In the course of one rotation, you have to rotation about ONE axis, whose coordinate would remain unchanged.

If it is a rotation matrix, in convention it means you rotation the vector COUNTERCLOCKWISELY (wiki is sometimes confusing :D) by angle $\theta$, while the matrix is 
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos\theta & -\sin\theta          \\
       \sin\theta & \cos\theta 
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

so, if 
$$
T_{1}(\alpha) = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha          \\
       \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha 
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
T_{2}(\gamma) = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos\gamma & -\sin\gamma          \\
       \sin\gamma & \cos\gamma 
     \end{bmatrix}
$$,

then $T_{2}^{-1}T_{1}\vec{x}$ means rotating $\vec{x}$ counterclockwisely by $\alpha$ then clockwisely by $\gamma$.
So actually you can use 
$$T_{2}^{-1}T_{1}\vec{x} = \tilde{T} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos(\alpha-\gamma) & -\sin(\alpha-\gamma)           \\
       \sin(\alpha-\gamma)  & \cos(\alpha-\gamma)  
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

Though it is equivalent in mathematics, it simplifies the computation a little bit and it also avoids inverse and matrix multiplication.

I only work in 2D because if the thrid dimension remains the same:
if
$$
T_{2}(\gamma) = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos\gamma & -\sin\gamma   &  0     \\
       \sin\gamma & \cos\gamma & 0 \\
0&0&1
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
the third entry of vector $\vec{x}$ wouldn't be changed.
So actually you can reduce the dimension.

I hope it helps a bit.
And using uppercase only means to grasp some attention and doesn't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: I have solved my issue. :) I am still not sure why, but If I to use $T_2*T_1^{-1}$ instead, then it works! My matrices handle only 2D case, not 3D. In my case the transform, may contain translation, scaling, skew too along with rotation.

Comment: that's good. But you do know that a hybrid(containing translation, scaling,tec) can be decomposed into separate matrices (which operate as simple translation, scaling, etc). May I ask if you are working on an issure relevant to continuum mechanics? if so, you should look into [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Matrix_polar_decomposition). It shows your transform can be always decomposed into skewing, rotation and translation. good luck with the rest.

Comment: @Apple: I'm guessing your system uses row vectors instead of column vectors?

Comment: @newbie I am using these matrices to draw stuffs on [HTML canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element).

Comment: @J.M. I am working with scalars. $P_i$ is just the xy of the point, no direction sense in that. I in fact have a [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/Etthp/7/) in Javascript which does exactly the thing I want, in exactly the way I expect it to. Unfortunately, the actual code where I wanted it to work is way too complicated. If I think trough that then maybe I might understand what is different there. Anyway, whatever works! :)

Comment: @AppleGrew since I don't know neither HTML nor javascript, I'll shut my mouth up. :D